# Spark Querying on all keys of a map

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a parquet file with the following schema

```
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Attendance: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Efficiency: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Where efficiency value ranges from -1 to +1 and the key is various categories such as Sports,Academics etc. I have up to 20 different keys.

I am trying to fetch the top 100 names ordered in descending by Attendance where efficiency[Key] is lesser than 0.
I am able to do this for one key. But i'm not able to figure out how I should be implementing this for all my keys simultaneously.
Code snippet for one key:

```
spark.sql("select Name,Attendance,Efficiency['Sports'] from data where Efficiency['Sports'] < 0 order by Attendance desc limit 100")
```

On doing some analysis I found that we would need to explode our map. But whenever I explode the number of rows in my table goes up and I am unable to fetch the top 100 names.

Sample Data for one key. The actual table has a map instead of the one column that is seen here

```
+--------------------+------------------+-------------+                         
|Name                |Attendance        |Efficiency[Sports]|
+--------------------+------------------+-------------+
|A                   |1000              |0.002        |
|B                   |365               |0.0          |
|C                   |1080              |0.193        |
|D                   |245               |-0.002       |
|E                   |1080              |-0.515       |
|F                   |905               |0.0          |
|G                   |900               |-0.001       |
```

Expected output : List of 100 names for each key

```
+-----------------------+--------------+                                        
|Sports                 |Academics     |
+-----------------------+--------------+
|A                      |A             |
|B                      |C             |
|C                      |D             |
|D                      |E             |
```

Any help on solving this would really helpful

Thanks

Comment: please update with your tried code for one key.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the code for one key!!

Comment: can you also show the value of Efficiency

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//dummy data
val d = Seq(
  ("a", 10, Map("Sports" -> -0.2, "Academics" -> 0.1)),
  ("b", 20, Map("Sports" -> -0.1, "Academics" -> -0.1)),
  ("c", 5, Map("Sports" -> -0.2, "Academics" -> 0.5)),
  ("d", 15, Map("Sports" -> -0.2, "Academics" -> 0.0))
).toDF("Name", "Attendence", "Efficiency")

//explode the map and get key value
val result = d.select($"Name", $"Attendence", explode($"Efficiency"))

//select value less than 0 and show 100
result.select("*").where($"value".lt(0))
  .sort($"Attendence".desc)
  .show(100)
```

Output:

```
+----+----------+---------+-----+
|Name|Attendence|key      |value|
+----+----------+---------+-----+
|b   |20        |Sports   |-0.1 |
|b   |20        |Academics|-0.1 |
|d   |15        |Sports   |-0.2 |
|a   |10        |Sports   |-0.2 |
|c   |5         |Sports   |-0.2 |
+----+----------+---------+-----+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. If my understanding is right this would give the top 100 attendance records. My expected output would be something like 
Sports : a, 20  b,19  c,18 d, 17 e,16
Academics : b,19 e,16 f,14 g,12

Comment: I'll update the question with an expected output block. Apologies for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

Given the input dataframe as

```
+----+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|Name|Attendance|Efficiency                               |
+----+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|A   |1000      |Map(Sports -> 0.002, Academics -> 0.002) |
|B   |365       |Map(Sports -> 0.0, Academics -> 0.0)     |
|C   |1080      |Map(Sports -> 0.193, Academics -> 0.193) |
|D   |245       |Map(Sports -> -0.002, Academics -> -0.46)|
|E   |1080      |Map(Sports -> -0.515, Academics -> -0.5) |
|F   |905       |Map(Sports -> 0.0, Academics -> 0.0)     |
|G   |900       |Map(Sports -> -0.001, Academics -> -0.0) |
+----+----------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Using `udf` function to iterate the `Map` for checking less than zero values. This can be done as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val isLessThan0 = udf((maps: Map[String, Double]) => maps.map(x => x._2 < 0).toSeq.contains(true))

df.withColumn("lessThan0", isLessThan0('Efficiency))
    .filter($"lessThan0" === true)
    .orderBy($"Attendance".desc)
    .drop("lessThan0")
    .show(100, false)
```

you will have output as

```
+----+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|Name|Attendance|Efficiency                               |
+----+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|E   |1080      |Map(Sports -> -0.515, Academics -> -0.5) |
|G   |900       |Map(Sports -> -0.001, Academics -> -0.0) |
|D   |245       |Map(Sports -> -0.002, Academics -> -0.46)|
+----+----------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. Please correct me if I'm wrong(I''m new to spark). Here you have written a user defined function that returns true if map[2] < 0 and added that to a new column. and sorted on those columns where this is set to true?

Comment: yes i have used udf function and in udf function i have iterated through the Map to check for values less then 0 if found then true else false. and filtered the true ones as your requirement is such and then i have ordered in descending order to show top 100